# Replace @remi packages with base packages

Tags: centos, yum, centos6.5, email-server

while installing iRedMail, I ran into the issues that some of my old packages were installed or updated by the Remi repo. I have disabled the epel and remi repos now, ran `yum update all` and I still get this error when trying to install iRedMail.

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
Error: Package: php-ldap-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
           Installed: php-common-5.4.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.30-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
Error: Package: php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Is there any way to replace these packages? I was thinking about uninstalling them, but I'm worried if that would case any problems with my existing server configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

wrong way, you have to enable remi repo, because you have php already installed from remi.
if you have problem installing iRedMail with remi enabled, so you better post that error.

Comment: The remi repo is disabled by default and needs to be explicitly enabled. Otherwise you see errors like this one.